# Should I roll my own replacement for c2WTS on .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, wif

I have a requirement to create a Windows Token from a UPN (retrieved via a Claim) to impersonate a user to a backend system using kerberos. This is for an API to be consumed by multiple internal applications (and potentially other external applications in the future).

So far, I have successfully managed to work out all the steps to get this working:

- Use new WindowsIdentity(upn) constructor to create a Token from the UPN
- Give the account "Act as part of operating system" privilege
- Set-up constrained delegation for the account to the back-end service in active directory

This works great when I then call Impersonate() on the WindowsIdentity and call the back-end service.

However, I now have an issue from a security point of view that I don't want my API service account to have the "Act as part of operating system" privilege.

Originally I found the c2WTS service, but this no longer is part of WIF since .NET 4.5 so I don't want to use this if at all possible to get the token (as it would be a separate feature to install and runs using .NET 3.5).

I've had a look at it's implementation and it is almost identical to what I would want to do

- Run as a windows service as the System account (so by default has the "Act as part of operating system" privilege
- Use IPC to allow my api service account to request a Token from this service

So my question really boils down to 2 things:

- Was there a reason for this being removed and no longer being part of .NET 4.5 and WIF 4.5?
- Should I roll my own c2WTS service using .NET 4.5 instead?

Comment: Don't roll your own. Just install the Windows feature. They are 100% compatible and intended to be used together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Steve's comment I've gone with installing the Windows Feature and it's working as expected.